# Darken element color

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to change the background color of an element when the mouseEnter event fires. How to make the color of the background darker?? I thought I can use an opacity mask, but it's a gradient, but I need it to be solid. Also it has to be in visual basic code, not in xaml.
Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opacity mask is not a very good option as it modifies the opacity. Also, the opacitymask can be any kind of brush it doesn't have to be a gradient.

You could do one of two things: manipulate the current brush or add a black rectangle on top of the control and change the opacity of the rectangle.

If you let me know what you prefer I could write some code.

(Why does it have to be code and not xaml?)

**EDIT**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApplication"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">

    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Background="Red"
                     FontSize="24" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="overlay"
                       Fill="Black"
                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                       Opacity="0" />
            <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation To="0.9"
                                             Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="overlay"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Opacity)" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation To="0"
                                             Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="overlay"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Opacity)" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Ok, can you show me an example to darken a red rectangle? What's the difference between those two options? It seems that adding a rectangle would be slower. It has to be in code, 'cause the elements are dinamicly added.

Comment: @Cobold: Dynamically adding items normally does not mean that you need to write code-behind in WPF just to display them correctly.

Comment: @H.B. So how will you change the rectangle's fill to be darker only in xaml, If you don't have nothing to set the properties on?

Comment: @Cobold: As Erno said you can just use an overlay, there is only one item that is being hovered over so there is only one additional rectangle at any point in time. Should not be much of a problem in terms of performace.

Comment: I thought of a couple of issues so I adjusted my example: overlay does no longer capture clicks, the mouse enter and leave are now attached to the events of the containing grid.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a [`ValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) for this. Recently used this converter to change opacity:

```cs
public class ChangeColorOpacityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color input = (Color)value;
        input.A = byte.Parse((string)parameter); //Changes alpha to ValueConverterParameter
        return input;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You could change this to darken the color, just divide all colour channels by two for example.

---

VC usage example:

```xml
<Border>
    <Border.Resources>
        <vc:DarkenColorConverter x:Key="DarkenColorConverter"/>
    </Border.Resources>
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding MyColor, Converter={StaticResource DarkenColorConverter}}"/>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

If you make use of the parameter you need to specify the value in the binding as `ConverterParameter`.

Comment: Can you please write in visual basic "Color input = (Color)value;"?

Comment: I found how to write it. But it says: Class 'ChangeColorOpacityConverter' must implement 'Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object' for interface 'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter'.

Comment: Have a look at the example in the reference i linked to. Also added an example to my answer. You probably want to apply this via trigger though.

Comment: @H.B. Thank you for your effort, but I found Erno storyboard better.

Comment: Animations are nice so Erno's answer is preferrable indeed if the change is dynamic (my opcaity converter only changed the color in my application once, so there is no apprupt change). You can upvote answers now (requires 15 rep) as you might have noticed, so if you indend to give me some credit anyway you could do so.